# Insert statement with variables failing

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

new here
I've come across this problem.

It doesn't seem to be able to use my id's from the two first statements in my last statements as a variable resource, so the sqlcharacter statement fails.

What do i do wrong?

```
$sqlimg = ("INSERT INTO cimages(image) VALUES(?)");
$stmtimg = $conn->prepare($sqlimg);
$stmtimg->bind_param('s', $image);
$stmtimg->execute();
$img_id = $stmtimg->insert_id;

// I insert the picture first, and retrieve it's ID

$sqlstats = ("INSERT INTO cstats(Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, 
Intelligence, Wisdom, Charisma, Aligment) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmtstats = $conn->prepare($sqlstats);
$stmtstats->bind_param("iiiiiis", $strength, $dexterity, $constitution, 
$intelligence, $wisdom, $charisma, $aligment);
$stmtstats->execute();
$stats_id = $stmtstats->insert_id;

// I insert the characters stats, and retrieve it's ID
// Last I insert The user_id and img_id and stats_id
$user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_id']);
// I've used the session id to get the user_id already 


$sqlcharacter = ("INSERT INTO characters(Cname, Clast, Crace, house, 
location, Bgstory, user_id, img_id, stats_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
$img_id, $stats_id)");
$stmtChar = $conn->prepare($sqlcharacter);
$stmtChar->bind_param('ssssssiii', $Cname, $Clast, $Crace, $house, 
$location, $Bgstory, $user_id, $img_id, $stats_id);
$stmtChar->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$sqlcharacter` string looks like you've got two variables `$img_id` and `$stats_id` in there instead of `?`, so I think that's why it's not binding those values.

**Try changing this:**

```
"INSERT INTO characters(Cname, Clast, Crace, house, 
 location, Bgstory, user_id, img_id, stats_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
 $img_id, $stats_id)"
```

**To this:**

```
"INSERT INTO characters(Cname, Clast, Crace, house, 
 location, Bgstory, user_id, img_id, stats_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
 ?, ?)"
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The last 3 Id's are foreign keys, and if i set as a ?, then it puts nothing into the database.

Comment: Could i do something like this?

        "INSERT INTO characters(Cname, Clast, Crace, house, location, 
         Bgstory, user_id, img_id, stats_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
         WHERE img_id='$img_id' AND stats_id='$stats_id'

Comment: That is correct, i've just realized, but it still don't work, so i've got some other mistake that i can't find